# Display Album Art in Android Music App

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to include the Album Art out of a mp3 file into my application, but it says:
Call to getEmbeddedPicture failed.

In my Song class I set the artwork of each song :

```
metaDataRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaDataRetriver.setDataSource(path);
//path = /mnt/sdcard/chan_mp3/Titel.mp3
byte[] artwork = metaDataRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
```

In my CustomAdapter I try to display the cover:

```
// This code works perfectly fine: for each song I get artist and title
textView.setText(values.get(position).getArtist() + " - " + values.get(position).getTitle());

// This code doesn't work at all
byte[] artwork = values.get(position).getArtwork();
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(artwork, 0, artwork.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

The question is where am I missing something? is the artwork variable not initialyzed correctly or is my request wrong?

Or is there a better approach to get the Album Cover and music information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another way to do it... I will save each albumId for each song and then I can fetch the cover art with the following code:

```
          Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
          Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Integer.valueOf(albumId));
          ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
          InputStream in;
          try {
              in = res.openInputStream(uri);
              artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

Comment: Doesn't it make the list very laggy ? How do you improve the performance?

Comment: can you please provide the source